# Trying to set image heights using window.innerHeight with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to set the height of three images so that each one of them fits the innerheight of the browser, but I can't get it to work.

Index:

```
<img id="mindmap" src="~/content/bilder/mindmap02.jpg" />
<img id="mindmap" src="~/content/bilder/mindmap03.jpg" />
<img id="mindmap" src="~/content/bilder/mindmap01.jpg" />
```

CSS:

```
width: auto;
display:block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Script:

```
function imageHeight() {

    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;

    if (w > h) {
        document.getElementById("mindmap").style.height = h -50 + "px";
    }
}
imageHeight();
window.onresize = function () {
    imageHeight();
};
```

Please help me! :(

**SOLVED:**

```
function imageHeight() {

    var w = window.innerWidth - 50;
    var h = window.innerHeight - 50;

    if (w > h) {
        document.getElementById('mindmap').style.width = h + 'px';
        document.getElementById('mindmap2').style.width = h + 'px';
        document.getElementById('mindmap3').style.width = h + 'px';
    }
}
imageHeight();
window.onresize = function () {
    imageHeight();
};
```

I used style.width because the images are square and it made them more responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Use Id's for unique elements and classes when you want multiple elements to be 'IDed'. Right now you're trying to find three elements at once.

Will the number of images be static? It isn't a dynamic solution but if you will only have three images you could put a reference to them in an array, then use a for loop to go over said array. With each pass it could run the function on an image, checking it's size and resizing if needed.

If you are to stick to using IDs you should change them (mindmap1, mindmap2...).

Comment: The images will be static so it's no need for them to be dynamic.
I will try the for loop thing you recommended, but won't that solution slow the website down because it runs the function all the time?
Thanks for the answer btw :)

Comment: The loop will run when the function is called, and go over each image. I assumed this was to be determined when the page loads, in which case the function just needs to be loaded once. You could watch if the page is resized and run the function when there's a resize. If dealing with resizing you may want to look into [Responsive Web Design](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/?hl=en). I also realized you could work with [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).